# Why does the Page speed index flactuate between normal browser mode and Incognito mode?

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to take Pagespeed index from [Google page speed service](https://pagespeed.web.dev/). I'm seeing that there is a difference between the speed scores between the normal browser mode and incognito mode. Is there a reason this is happening?

I tried to take pagespeed index in normal browser mode and incognito mode, and the values should be similar but they are showing different scores. we are getting a difference of 60 - 20 range.